# ClassNotFoundException when using SerializationUtils.clone()

Tags: java

```
org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.anonymized.bean.Person
        at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:166)
        at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:193)
        at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.clone(SerializationUtils.java:81)
        at com.anonymized.CallingClass.handleRequestInternal(CallingClass.java:45)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.anonymized.bean.Person
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

The call that's throwing the exception.

```
Person copy = (Person) SerializationUtils.clone(PersonHolder.getPerson(request));
```

- `PersonHolder.getPerson(request)` DOES return a `Person`
- `Person` implements `Serializable`
- `request` is an HttpServletRequest which has data that is being passed to the method in which I try to clone the `Person`. It contains data that the `getPerson` method needs. I don't believe this has anything to do with my problem but I just wanted to be clear what it was doing.
- The `commons-lang-2.4.jar` is included in my project.
- I've imported `org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils` and the `Person` class.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: it seems the class is not in the path during execution

Comment: your version of commons-lang screws up classloading (especially not using person.getClass().getClassLoader() to deserialize it). You should go to a more recent version. (commons-lang-2.4 is 10 years old)

Comment: @k5_ Moved to the latest and that did the trick! Thankyou!

Answer (score 3):

try importing org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.